# on orientation change JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, mobile, web

i have a problem with the orientation change function, i'm trying to change the width of some elements in my "slide show" when the orientation is changing, i dont know why but it does not work.
i checked the orientation event with alert and suddenly after i confirmd the alert everything worked and when im removing the alert from the code it returns to the old problem and nothing seems to change.

i searched for answer in the search line but didnt find a solution this is my code:

```
$( window ).on( "orientationchange", function(event){
    alert(event.orientation);

    clearInterval(slideShowInterval);

    slideWidth = $(window).width();
    slides.css({ 'float' : 'left' , 'width' :slideWidth});
    $('#slidesHolder').css({
        'width' : slideWidth * numberOfSlides,
        'direction' : 'ltr'
    });

    slideShowInterval = setInterval(changePosition, speed);
    moveSlide();

})
```

Comment: I've had similar issues in the past - the worst part is if you query the element, you'll find that the browser thinks it's the new width, just visually it's not reflected (aggressive caching on the browser side?) There are different ways I've gotten around it - One is placing the `.css` call into a setTimeout, and allow the browser to complete the orientation change, and then call `slides.css`, which will force the browser to do a separate reflow.

Comment: i tries to set time out and the look of it is a mess, i counldn't tell what was changed so i just putted background black for the slides and the color did changed but the problem with the dimensions still remains.